# Compare objects's properties values but not objects type

Tags: java, junit, mockito, hamcrest

is possible to compare objects of two different types compare with mockito or hamcrest ? For example below I show examples of my objects.

ObjectA:

```
public class ObjectA {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private AddressA address
    // getters and setters
}
```

ObjectB:

```
public class ObjectB {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private AddressB address
    // getters and setters
}
```

Objects AddressA and AddressB are also with same named properties, but only different types. Is it possible, and if yes how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `hamcrest` API, you can achieve it by following

```
ObjectA A = new ObjectA(1, "ABC", new AddressA("jkl"));
ObjectB B = new ObjectB(1, "PQR", new AddressB("xyz"));

assertThat(A, hasProperty("id", equalTo(B.getId())));
assertThat(A, hasProperty("name", equalTo(B.getName())));
assertThat(A.getAddressA(), hasProperty("address", equalTo(B.getAddressB().getAddress())));
```

Comment: Honestly, how is this better readable then `assertEquals(A.getId(), B.getId());`?

Comment: well, OP wanted to make sure there exists a property on both the objects - your `assert` only makes sure the values are equal.